# Picture rotates behind the screen, 1px issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I'm having issues with this slider : http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/home2 When I open the site on the Google Chrome Dev tools I see that the issue comes from `<div id="featured" class="orbit" style="width: 1px; height: 370px; ">`the 1px is blocking the picture and I've checked my CSS and there is nothing, i don't know how to get rid of the 1px. Can someone point me or help me out?

Answer (score 0):

your `div` ID "featured" has style `width:1px;`

EDIT: sorry i forgot to say, its not in `css` its inline style or added dynamically by some JavaScript. Check your html source and remove style="width:1px;" on that div or specify the right dimension.

btw. if you don't have i suggest you to install firebug, will save you much time and nerves!

Comment: I checked my html and there's is no sign of the 1px. I think it was dynamically added like you said. What can I do in that case?

Comment: Check your JavaScript files, remove them then try, try disable JavaScript in browser and try, or maybe you have trying to add some kind of different slideshow which goes from left to right and you left it so it mess up with new one. Check your JavaScript files for "featured".

Comment: Disabling JavaScript wont help when this image is from slider which is JavaScript powered, well than maybe in some setup of this slider.

Comment: It's the orbit plugin.  When it first loads it sets the width to 1px.  Something is going wrong with the plugin and the width doesn't ever get updated.

Comment: I think I see the 1px in the plugin. What should I do?

Comment: Okay I edited the plugin and it works. Thank you Mark and Fertoll for the help.